# Bypassing Shipping Options for FREE shipping

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

I asked this question previously and am still having trouble.  I want to bypass shipping options for items with free shipping.

I added this code to the shipping options page:

```
 {if order_shipping_val == 0}
    {redirect="Store/Confirm-Order"}
{/if}
```

Unfortunately it redirects for all items including ones that should have paid shipping.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that, you need to make sure your regular orders definitely have a shipping cost. You should make sure there is a default shipping method set, and that there is a default country/state set as well, so that all orders have a shipping cost associated with them as soon as an item is added to the cart.

To debug it, try outputting `{order_shipping}` directly onto the page instead of the redirect code, and make sure that it returns a non-zero value even for new carts.

EDIT: If you are using the UPS extension it's a bit more difficult, because you can't set UPS as the default shipping method. You will need to check if the cart has a valid shipping method, and if not, reload the page.

First, I would delete any regular shipping methods you have set up (if you are 100% using UPS for shipping).

Then, create a check to make sure the current cart has a shipping method selected before redirecting to the next step:

```
{if shipping_method == ""}
    {field:shipping_method}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#next-button").click(); // trigger a form submit
    </script>
{if:else}
    {!-- now we know a shipping method has been selected --}
    {if order_shipping_val == 0}
        {redirect="Store/Confirm-Order"}
    {/if}
{/if}

<input type="submit" id="next-button" />
```

Comment: Thank you your quick response.  Unfortunately, I'm still having a issue.  I go from Add to Cart > Check Out > Shipping Address > Shipping Options.  I add the {order_shipping} variable which comes back as $0 every time. The added shipping options like UPS with correct prices show, though. I added a default shipping option, but no luck.  Any idea?  Thank you.

Comment: Oh ok it's going to be different if you are using the UPS extension (because you can't set UPS as the default shipping method). See my edit above.